# How to fill the Array with the rand Function?

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, while-loop, do-while

I want to fill a matrix starting from the center. After this, I must supply positions with the rand () function, the stop condition being to find a position where the neighbor has a value of 1 allocated. This must be done until you reach the boundary of the matrix, that is, a for x or y when they assume position 0 or (size-1)

```
x = y = (size + 1) / 2;
   matrix[x][y]=1;                   //default of the matrix
    do{
       x1=rand() %(size-1);          //random position in x
       y1=rand() %(size-1);          // random position in y
       matrix[x1][y1]=1;             //declare the value in the position obtained
    }while((matrix[x1-1][y1  ]==0)||
           (matrix[x1+1][y1  ]==0)||
           (matrix[x1  ][y1-1]==0)|| 
           (matrix[x1  ][y1+1]==0)||
           (x1==x)||(y1==y));
```

My main question is whether my conditional is true, and how could I stop this bond when I reach the boundary of the matrix.

Comment: What do you mean by "fill a matrix starting from the center"?

Comment: Seems like a floodfill task?

Comment: That is, to declare initially that the position of the center is 1, and after that select its random random positions until the position obtained is next. Thus, you will have a matrix filled from the center when you will print it.

Comment: You **must** check the bounds of the array indexing, before anything else. An alternative is to make the matrix 2 elements bigger in each direction, initialise, and use the invalid value instead of checking the index bounds.

Comment: As well? What I had in mind was to create a loop for each value until I found a neighboring position occupied with value 1, and then an outer loop that is limited to iterations according to the dimensions of the array

Comment: The idea is as in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zgpRf7b-qF8, but using zeros and ones

Comment: "how could I stop this bond when I reach the boundary of the matrix" - by checking the array index values.

Comment: Could you show me how? It's not clear how I would do this.

Answer (score 0):

To move outward from the center of the matrix, select a square around the center and iterate through the elements in that square. Here is an example which works with a matrix with an odd size. You can add additional conditions for setting the value based on the value of the neighbors.

```
int main(void)
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int size = 21;
    int **matrix = malloc(size * sizeof(int*));
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        matrix[i] = malloc(size * sizeof(int));

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = 0;

    int center = size / 2 + 1;
    matrix[center][center] = 1;
    for(int range = 1; range < size / 2; range++)
    {
        for(int i = center - range; i < center + range; i++)
            for(int j = center - range; j < center + range; j++)
            {
                if(
                    (i == (center - range))||
                    (j == (center - range))||
                    (i == (center + range - 1))||
                    (j == (center + range - 1))
                    )
                    if(rand() % 2)
                        matrix[i][j] = 1;
            }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            printf("%d", matrix[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```